# New Bootstrap version: Unknown provider: $animateCssProvider <- $animateCss <- $uibModalStack <- $uibModal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Having some issues. Probably a versions issue: my versions are below. I tried downgrading my ui.bootstrap and angular-bootstrap to no avail. Any thoughts are welcome. Thanks!

```
"angular": "1.5.8",
 "ui.bootstrap": "^1.3.3",
    "angular-bootstrap": "0.13.0",
```

Comment: put some code for what you ar doing or just. change the bower version and redonwload?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed in the end. I tweaked my angular-ui-bootstrap to match the angularjs versions and animate.css . Had to downgrade ui.bootstrap.